# Sorting array by max distance

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've got a list of unique integers, and I want to sort them so that the next integer is always as far from all the rest, an it's possible.

For example, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} => {1,9,6,2,8,3,7,4,5}

And I need to do it really fast.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
    static double GetDistanceIndex(int value, List<int> others)
    {
        double result=0;
        foreach (var other in others)
        {
            result += Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(other - value));
        }

        return result;
    }

    static List<int> Sort(List<int> items, int initialValue)
    {
        items = items.ToList();
        List<int> result=new List<int>();


        lock (rnd)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                result.Add(initialValue);
                items.Remove(initialValue);
                if (items.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Dictionary<double, List<int>> distances = new Dictionary<double, List<int>>();
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var d = GetDistanceIndex(item, result);
                    if (!distances.ContainsKey(d))
                    {
                        distances[d] = new List<int>();
                    }
                    distances[d].Add(item);
                }

                var max = distances.Keys.Max();
                var l = distances[max];
                //if (l.Count == 1)
                //{
                //    initialValue = l[0];
                //}
                //else
                //{
                initialValue = l[rnd.Next(l.Count)];
                //} 
            } 
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But the problem is, that implemented like this, the algorithm will work extremely slowly for large arrays.

Can anyone suggest to me a better way to do it?

**UPDATE**

Here's a better description what was done:

{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}=>

1. initial seed : 1. Really, it can be any number. We can select 5, and get something like {5,9,1,2,8,3,7,6,4}
2. From the provided array, 9 is the farthest away from 1 by distances
3. Because in the list all the numbers are equidistant from 1 and from 9, we can select any of them. I used rand to select 6.
4. Now we are looking for a number farthest away from {1,9,6}. 
   2 is selected because `abs(2-1)+abs(2-9)+abs(2-6)=12` and is greater than `abs(3-1)+abs(3-9)+abs(3-6)=11` or `abs(4-1)+abs(4-9)+abs(4-6)=10` or `abs(8-1)+abs(8-9)+abs(8-6)=10`  or `abs(7-1)+abs(7-9)+abs(7-6)=9` or `abs(5-1)+abs(5-9)+abs(5-6)=9`
5. etc

**UPDATE 1**

I'm using  this algorithm to select numbers as different from each other as possible from a fixed number of alternatives

**UPDATE 2**

Dukeling in his answer pointed out to me, that {1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5} also conforms to my requirements. This was true, and it's my mistake. I want the numbers to be as far spaced as possible, and 3d number being very close to the first one is not what I intended. So I'm updating the distance function to reflect this

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean be "far from the rest"? Do you want the sum of absolute values of differences between the adjacent values to be maximum?

Comment: I need the differences. Absolute values don't matter. See `GetDistanceIndex`

Comment: Your description of how you want to sort and your example aren’t clear.

Comment: Why did you pick 6 instead of 5 for the 3rd item?

Comment: @HotLicks they are all equidistant, so you can pick any of them. On that stage, I used rand to select the text one

Comment: So now you described the parts where you _randomly_ pick a number – but you left out the _interesting_ part, which number you want to pick after you selected 1,9,6 …

Comment: By reading GetDistanceIndex, you can see that he actually picks the number for which the sum of the distances to each of the already sorted numbers is maximum.

Comment: Is there a point to all this?  It seems like an odd "exercise".

Comment: CBroe as far as I understand its any number x not yet added to the resulting set `s` that maximizes `Sum[d(x, s[i])]` where the distance function `d(x,y)` is `abs(x-y)`.

Comment: @AndersForsgren minimizes? He picks the maximum, I think you meant "maximizes" instead.

Comment: What you can start with is not using `Remove` from large lists, its very inefficient. Are the input numbers distinct or can there be repeated numbers? If the input numbers are distinct you can use some Dictionary/HashSet

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves yes, corrected

Comment: @AndersForsgren yeah. Operations with lists can be fixed and updated. I'm just curious if anyone can suggest a way to do this sort without going through all the results over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edited to conform to new distance function]**

You are making unnecessary work by calling GetDistanceIndex() repeatedly. Notice that you don't need to sum everything from scratch everytime. If you have an array like this:

[a, b, c, d, ............, x]

Where a, b, c, and d are already sorted, then, when you insert a new element 'e', the sum of the distance function of any position 'x' in the unsorted set to all the other numbers in the sorted set is only increased by sqrt(abs(x-e)). You don't have to recompute the whole sum from scratch.

So here's how you can optimize it: use some kind of method to store a pair (number, distance). If you were using C, you could, for example, make an array of a structure with two integers, the value itself, and the distance to the sorted set. At each step, you go through every pair (number, distance) that is not in the sorted set and you update its distance attribute. You can keep track of the maximum at the same time. Some pseudo-code:

- Create an auxiliary buffer S, to hold pairs of (number, distance);
- Insert every number x different from initialValue in S, with distance = sqrt(abs(initialValue - x)). Keep track of the maximum, m, at the same time;
- In each step, pick m and move it to the sorted piece of the array.
  Remove it from S. Then, go to every element y in S and add
  sqrt(abs(y.number-m.number)) to y's distance. Again, you need to keep track
  of the maximum as you do this. Keep repeating that until every
  element is sorted.

It's not a brilliant solution; it runs in O(n^2), but your current algorithm runs in O(n^3) because GetDistanceIndex() always starts from scratch. Also, I wouldn't use lists and dictionaries, try to use a simple array, so that you can access and delete elements in constant time. Deleting from a list can be inefficient, it never gets better than O(log(n)).

At the moment, that's the only optimization I can think of, maybe someone will have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

`{1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5}` seems to conform to your requirements, and is fairly easy to generate.

Just sort the numbers in ascending / descending order (if not already done).

Then iterate from both the back and the front, alternating between them until we get to the middle. This step runs in linear time.

Comment: except that 3d element will be always close to element 1 etc, which I'd also like to avoid. Ideally for me, after 9 would come 5