# Sorting Data by having the larger numbers spread out the best way

Tags: c#, sorting

I am not sure how to explain this. Might be a simple thing to do, but English not being my first language, it is hard for me to research this topic.

I selected C# as a tag, because that is what I am using, but it is not necessarily a C# issue, more like a sorting thing.

I will give you an example.

Let's say I have this array, with these values:

```
0, 0, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1
```

I need to sort these numbers in a way so the **biggest values would be as far from each other as possible**. I am doing some type of data visualization, and the best way the data would look like is having the 6,7,8 from the above example have small values between them. There is no need for a perfect way to sort, just an optimized set would be needed. As help, you need to imagine that **the first value of the set is right next to the last value of the set, so you cannot put the first value to have a  big one and the last one too**.

A good way that the above numbers would look like would be for example:

```
1, 6, 2, 0, 7, 1, 2, 5, 0, 2, 8, 2
```

As you can see the larger numbers 5-6-7-8 have smaller ones 0-1-2 between them to spread out.
There might be other ways to sort for the same set.

An algorithm would be fine, but I would feel pretty good also if this way of sorting data would have a specific name that you give me so I can research on it.

Thank you

Comment: don't know a name, but define two or more classes (value ranges), fill them, and then random-pick weighted by the number of items in each class, for a start. basic working principle like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192640/1132334, or a simpler trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/19208844/1132334

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting array by max distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208576/sorting-array-by-max-distance)

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface The guy has a similar thing, I see a difference that he has unique integers, mine are not unique. I will try to see if I can use it for my case. Both his answers make some sense, the 2nd , the simpler one does not look good enough at first glance, will try to see if I can implement something like the 1st one. Thanks